# Python code to create an array of arrays (8x8 with each being a 3x3)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am attempting to create an array of arrays with the structure being an 8x8, where each cell in that is a 3x3 array. What I have created works, but when I want to change a specific value, I need to access it differently than I would expect.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((3,3))
b = np.array([[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0]])
d = np.array([[b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a]])
e = np.array([[a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b]])
g = np.array([[d],[e],[d],[e],[d],[e],[d],[e]])

#Needed to change a specific cell 
#g[0][0][0][0][0][0] = x : [Row-x][0][0][Cell-x][row-x][cell-x]
#Not sure why I have to have the 2 0's between the Row-x and the Cell-x identifiers
```

After this, I will need to map each value to a 24x24 grid with 1's having a different color than 0's. If anyone could provide direction to achieve this, it would be appreciated. Not looking for the specific code, but a base to understand how it can be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [291]: a = np.zeros((3,3)) 
     ...: b = np.array([[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0]]) 
     ...: d = np.array([[b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a]]) 
     ...: e = np.array([[a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b]]) 
     ...: g = np.array([[d],[e],[d],[e],[d],[e],[d],[e]])                       

In [292]: a.shape                                                               
Out[292]: (3, 3)
In [293]: b.shape                                                               
Out[293]: (3, 3)
```

`d` is 4d - count the brackets: `[[....]]`:

```
In [294]: d.shape                                                               
Out[294]: (1, 8, 3, 3)
In [295]: e.shape                                                               
Out[295]: (1, 8, 3, 3)
```

`g` is (8,1) of 4 dim elements, for a total of 6.  Again count the brackets:

```
In [296]: g.shape                                                               
Out[296]: (8, 1, 1, 8, 3, 3)
```

Accessing a 2d subarray, in this case equal to `b`:

```
In [298]: g[0,0,0,0,:,:]                                                        
Out[298]: 
array([[0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0.]])
```

Redo, without the excess brackets:

```
In [299]: a = np.zeros((3,3)) 
     ...: b = np.array([[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0]]) 
     ...: d = np.array([b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a]) 
     ...: e = np.array([a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b]) 
     ...: g = np.array([d,e,d,e,d,e,d,e])                                       
In [300]: d.shape                                                               
Out[300]: (8, 3, 3)
In [301]: g.shape                                                               
Out[301]: (8, 8, 3, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining that.